# Data persistence of CouchDb in Hyperledger Fabroc 1.2 (Fabcar Example)

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

Can anyone help me on how can I persist my data  between hyperledger network restarts so that I don’t loose the data. I have seen posts regarding persisting the volume but I am not sure how do I utilize that functionality.  In Fabcar Demo I am storing the data of Cars . If I restart the network I dont want to loose the Car data so that next time if I query if it should have the old data which was stored in couchdb. I would really like to know how we do data persistence.

```
# Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
#
version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/f3ce2cb6ebdbca37bc08aa843df1e34fd3e4fad8b404c3490f993d5d83556bdb_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - /var/hyperledger/peer0:/var/hyperledger/production
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - basic

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - basic
    volumes:
      - /var/hyperledger/couchdb0:/opt/couchdb/data

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - basic
```

Answer (score 0):

As per as the [documentation here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html?highlight=couchdb%20data%20persistence#a-note-on-data-persistence), all you need to do is change the docker compose file so that couchDB uses a host directory to mount its data.

For peer section in the file, add these two lines:

```
volumes:
- /var/hyperledger/peer0:/var/hyperledger/production
```

For Couchdb section, add:

```
volumes:
- /var/hyperledger/couchdb0:/opt/couchdb/data
```

And now spin up the network using the update docker compose file.

Comment: This is what I got when I tried that. "Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: cannot create ledger from genesis block: LedgerID already exists)". I am updating my question to include the docker compose file I am using.

Comment: you probably did not delete your old containers. The error likely means you are trying to create a channel with a name that already exists in the network. To delete all containers, do `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`. Disclaimer, This will delete *all* existing containers, not the fabric ones only.

Comment: I am already doing that before the start of the script. I am using fabcar as an example to run my demo. I am not sure what is the issue as I am calling docker rm to remove all the running containers

Comment: The error you mentioned means that you are trying to join a peer that already joined.

Comment: when we restart network the peer joins the existing network because it has a mounted volume. What are the commands that we need to run when we restart the network???

Comment: Ok, try to delete the mounted volumes in host and then restart the network.

Comment: that means I have to delete only the mounted volumes in peer not in chaincode right? Because when I delete both it works perfectly fine but I am unable to persist the data. I will delete the host mounted volumes and will try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181363/discussion-between-chika-and-adnan-c).